# How to compare two sequential strings in a file

Tags: powershell

I have a big file consists of "before" and "after" cases for every item as follows:

```
case1 (BEF) ACT
      (AFT) BLK
case2 (BEF) ACT
      (AFT) ACT
case3 (BEF) ACT
      (AFT) CLC
...
```

I need to select all of the strings which have `(BEF) ACT` on the "first" string and `(AFT) BLK` on the "second" and place the result to a file.

The idea is to create a clause like

```
IF (stringX.LineNumber consists of "(BEF) ACT" AND stringX+1.LineNumber consists of (AFT) BLK)
{OutFile $stringX+$stringX+1}
```

Sorry for the syntax, I've just starting to work with PS :)

```
$logfile = 'c:\temp\file.txt'
$matchphrase = '\(BEF\) ACT'
$linenum=Get-Content $logfile | Select-String $matchphrase | ForEach-Object {$_.LineNumber+1}
$linenum 
#I've worked out how to get a line number after the line with first required phrase
```

Create a new file with a result as follows:
string with "(BEF) ACT" following with a string with "(AFT) BLK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select-String -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive '(BEF) ACT' c:\temp\file.txt -Context 0,1 |
  ForEach-Object {
    $lineAfter = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
    if ($lineAfter.Contains('(AFT) BLK')) {
      $_.Line, $lineAfter  # output
    }
  } # | Set-Content ...
```

- `-SimpleMatch` performs string-literal substring matching, which means you can pass the search string as-is, without needing to escape it.

  - However, if you needed to further constrain the search, such as to ensure that it only occurs at the end of a line (`$`), you would indeed need a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) with the (implied) `-Pattern` parameter: `'\(BEF\) ACT$'`
  - Also note PowerShell is generally case-*insensitive* by default, which is why switch `-CaseSensitive` is used.
- Note how [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) can accept file paths directly - no need for a preceding `Get-Content` call.
- `-Context 0,1` captures `0` lines *before* and `1` line *after* each match, and includes them in the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instances that `Select-String` outputs.
- Inside the `ForEach-Object` script block, `$_.Context.PostContext[0]` retrieves the line *after* the match and `.Contains()` performs a literal substring search in it.

  - Note that `.Contains()` is a method of the .NET `System.String` type, and such methods - unlike PowerShell - are case-*sensitive* by default, but you can use an optional parameter to change that.
- If the substring is found on the subsequent line, both the line at hand and the subsequent one are output.
- The above looks for *all* matching pairs in the input file; if you only wanted to find the *first* pair, append `| Select-Object -First 2` to the `Select-String` call.

Comment: Brilliant!I have to read more about regular expressions. Thank you so much !

Comment: I've developed some other approach using -Pattern and -Context:

$infile = 'c:\temp\blablafile.txt'

Select-String -Pattern '\(BEF\) ACT' $infile -Context 0,1 |
  ForEach-Object {
    $lineAfter = $_.Context.PostContext[0]

    if ($lineAfter.Contains('(AFT) BLK')) {
         
    $_.Line, $lineAfter      }
      }

Comment: I see, @D.Kh. - looks like you switched from string-literal matching with `-SimpleMatch '(BEF) ACT'` back to regex-based matching with `-Pattern  '\(BEF\) ACT'`, as in your question. Note, though, that since your regex doesn't actually use any regex constructs, string-literal matching is both syntactically simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to read the $logFile in as a single string and use a RegEx match to get the parts you want:

```
$logFile = 'c:\temp\file.txt'
$outFile = 'c:\temp\file2.txt'

# read the content of the logfile as a single string
$content = Get-Content -Path $logFile -Raw

$regex = [regex] '(case\d+\s+\(BEF\)\s+ACT\s+\(AFT\)\s+BLK)'
$match = $regex.Match($content)
($output = while ($match.Success) {
    $match.Value
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}) | Set-Content -Path $outFile -Force
```

When used the result is:

```
case1 (BEF) ACT
      (AFT) BLK
case7 (BEF) ACT
      (AFT) BLK
```

Regex details:

> ```
> (              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    case        Match the characters “case” literally
>    \d          Match a single digit 0..9
>       +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    \s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    \(          Match the character “(” literally
>    BEF         Match the characters “BEF” literally
>    \)          Match the character “)” literally
>    \s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    ACT         Match the characters “ACT” literally
>    \s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    \(          Match the character “(” literally
>    AFT         Match the characters “AFT” literally
>    \)          Match the character “)” literally
>    \s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    BLK         Match the characters “BLK” literally
> )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

- [My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707895/45375) completes your own `Select-String`-based solution attempt. **`Select-String` is versatile, but slow**, though it is appropriate for processing files too large to fit into memory as a whole, given that it processes files *line by line*.

  - However, PowerShell offers **a *much faster* line-by-line processing alternative: 
    [`switch -File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch)** - see the solution below.
- [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55708204/45375), which reads the entire file into memory first, will probably perform best overall, depending on file size, but it comes at the cost of increased complexity, due to relying heavily on direct use of .NET functionality.

---

```
$(
  $firstLine = ''
  switch -CaseSensitive -Regex -File t.txt {
    '\(BEF\) ACT' { $firstLine = $_; continue }
    '\(AFT\) BLK' { 
      # Pair found, output it.
      # If you don't want to look for further pairs, 
      # append `; break` inside the block.
      if ($firstLine) { $firstLine, $_ }
      # Look for further pairs.
      $firstLine = ''; continue
    }
    default { $firstLine = '' }
  } 
) # | Set-Content ...
```

<sup>Note: The enclosing `$(...)` is only needed if you want to send the output directly to the pipeline to a cmdlet such as `Set-Content`; it is not needed for capturing the output in a *variable*: `$pair = switch ...`</sup>

- `-Regex` interprets the branch conditionals as [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions).
- `$_` inside a branch's action script block (`{ ... }` refers to the line at hand.
- The overall approach is:

  - `$firstLine` stores the 1st line of interest once found, and when the 2nd line's pattern is found and `$firstLine` is set (is nonempty), the pair is output.
  - The `default` handler resets `$firstLine`, to ensure that only two *consecutive* lines that contain the strings of interest are considered.

Comment: A really nice solution! Never thought of using `switch`. (+1)

Comment: Thanks, @Theo. Yes, `switch -File` is pretty handy, yet little-known, presumably because similar constructs in other languages have no built-in file-processing ability, so people don't expect / remember it.